# How to signal the end of stdin input

Tags: command-line, terminal, signals

1. In Bash, I learned that the ending signal can be changed by here document. But by default how can I signal the end of `stdin` input?
2. I happened to find that with `cat` and `chardet`, their `stdin` inputs can be  signaled as finished by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. But I seems to remember that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> are similar to ending execution of a running command. So am I wrong?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>, when typed at the start of a line on a terminal, signifies the end of the input. This is not a [signal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_%28computing%29) in the unix sense: when an application is reading from the terminal and the user presses <kbd>Ctrl+D</kbd>, the application is notified that the end of the file has been reached (just like if it was reading from a file and had passed the last byte).

<kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> does send a signal, [SIGINT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGINT_%28POSIX%29). By default SIGINT (the interrupt signal) kills the foreground application, but the application can catch the signal and react in some different way (for example, the shell itself catches the signal and aborts the line you've begun typing, but it doesn't exit, it shows a new prompt and waits for a new command line).

<sub>You can change the characters associated with end-of-file and SIGINT with the [`stty`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/stty.html#tag_04_135_05_05) command, e.g. `stty eof a` would make `a` the end-of-file character, and `stty intr ^-` would disable the SIGINT character. This is rarely useful.</sub>

Comment: Thanks! Does`Ctrl+D` mean Ctrl and *capital* D or it doesn't matter?

Comment: @Tim: it's lower case you want ... the convention of writing keyboard commands with capitals comes because the labels on the keyboard are always in capitals and the thing being described is a KEY SEQUENCE not the actual character code that the program sees. Yes this is confusing sometimes.

Comment: @Caleb: Thanks! How shall one specify that the key is in capital? Or is there ever such case?

Comment: @Tim On a terminal, the key combinations `Ctrl+Shift+D` and `Ctrl+D` send the same character anyway (character number 4, usually called `Ctrl+D`).

Comment: @Tim: When specifying a key sequence to be entered by the user you would customarily include `Shift` in the sequence description as in Gilles' example above.

Comment: @Gilles: Now I see that Ctrl+D doesn't generate a signal, but is the end-of-transmission character. When typing Ctrl+D, is the end-of-transmission character read into the program that takes the stdin input, and used by the program to detect if the program has reached the end of transmission/fie? Or is the EOF character only seen by the shell to detect the end of transmission/file, before passing the stdin input to the program, and the EOF character is never passed into the program?

Comment: @Tim The *terminal* received Ctrl+D. It does not send a character to the program. What happens is that when the program reads from the terminal, the terminal tells it “this is the end of the file”, same as when a program tries to read after the end of a disk file. The shell is not involved at all.

Comment: Thanks. (1) So is the program not implemented to deal with the character of ctrl+D? Is it correct that ctrl+D is a control character, only meaningful to the terminal, not to the shell, the program or the Linux kernel? (2) How does the terminal notify the program the end of file? by a signal, a character, or ...?

Comment: @Tim `Ctrl+D` is interpreted as the ASCII control character EOT (end of transmission) when the sequence of key it is not caught by the terminal. To enter the EOT character, you can prevent the interpretation by the terminal by first sending `Ctrl+V` and then `Ctrl+D` (`Ctrl+V` makes that the next character is passed quoted, preventing it from being interpreted by the terminal) – see `man stty` and `stty -a`.

Answer (score 28):

Your second point lumps two completely different things together.

- Ctrl+C sends a kill signal to the running process.
- Ctrl+D sends an [End of Transmission](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-transmission_character) character.

You are looking for the latter.

Comment: Potential for confusion here: from the application perspective, no any actual character is sent for ^D. Which means that the application doesn't recieve that character from the `read(2)` syscall.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this while searching for other information. The answers provided are correct but I think too involved with the internal workings.

The simple, non-technical, answer is that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> terminates the STDIN file and that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> terminates the active application.

Both are handled in the keyboard driver and apply to all programs reading from the keyboard.

To see the difference start a command line shell and enter the `wc` command with no arguments. It is now waiting for STDIN input. Type a sentence and "return". Now type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and `wc` will complete and give you the line, word and character count.

Do the same thing but type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. wc will terminate with no output.

Comment: I do not think that either `Ctrl`+`D` and `Ctrl`+`C` are handed by the keyboard driver since their interpretation as EOF or SIGINT is a configurable terminal setting (see `man stty` and `stty -a`)