# Ctrl+D for ending terminal line input

Tags: command-line, terminal, cat

If I do

```
$ cat > file.txt
```

> text<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd>

Question 1: If I don't press enter, why do I have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> twice?

If I do

```
$ cat > file.txt
```

> pa bam pshhh<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>

```
[2]+  Stopped         cat > file.txt
$ cat file.txt
$ cat > file.txt
```

> pa bam pshhh
>
> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Z</kbd>

```
[2]+  Stopped         cat > file.txt
$ cat file.txt
pa bam pshhh
```

Why is the second time the file with 1 line?

Comment: This thread under the stackexchange sites umbrella have the answer you are looking at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7369170/why-do-i-have-to-type-ctrl-d-twice. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yeah, even though not python related, my question is a duplicate.

Comment: When you type ctrl-z, are you really getting just a new shell prompt, or are you also getting a message about `cat` being stopped?

Comment: I'll update the question

Answer (score 36, accepted):

In Unix, most objects you can read and write - ordinary files, pipes, terminals, raw disk drives - are all made to resemble files.

A program like `cat` reads from its standard input like this:

```
n = read(0, buffer, 512);
```

which asks for 512 bytes. `n` is the number of bytes actually read, or -1 if there's an error.

If you did this repeatedly with an ordinary file, you'd get a bunch of 512-byte reads, then a somewhat shorter read at the tail end of the file, then 0 if you tried to read past the end of the file. So, `cat` will run until `n` is <= 0.

Reading from a terminal is slightly different. After you type in a line, terminated by the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, `read` returns just that line.

There are a few special characters you can type. One is <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>. When you type this, the operating system sends all of the current line that you've typed (but not the <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> itself) to the program doing the read. And here's the serendipitous thing: if <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> is the first character on the line, the program is sent a line of length 0 - just like the program would see if it just got to the end of an ordinary file. `cat` *doesn't need to do anything differently*, whether it's reading from an ordinary file or a terminal.

Another special character is <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd>. When you type it, anywhere in a line, the operating system discards whatever you've typed up until that point and sends a SIGTSTP signal to the program, which normally stops (pauses) it and returns control to the shell.

So in your example

```
$ cat > file.txt
pa bam pshhh<Ctrl+Z>
[2]+  Stopped         cat > file.txt
```

you typed some characters that were discarded, then `cat` was stopped without having written anything to its output file.

```
$ cat > file.txt
pa bam pshhh
<Ctrl+Z>
[2]+  Stopped         cat > file.txt
```

you typed in one line, which `cat` read and wrote to its output file, and then the <kbd>Ctrl-Z</kbd> stopped `cat`.

Comment: these things are only true of [canonical mode terminals](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/basedefs/xbd_chap11.html). And even in that case they can be changed.

Comment: @mikeserv That's true. Here, I wanted to explain just what the OP was seeing. I considered also describing raw/-icanon terminal mode, other special characters, how they can be customized, how they differ by OS, etc. but didn't want to make the answer overly long.

Comment: Does the above imply that if input weren't going through `cat`, that a program which read data from the keyboard and didn't stop the first time `read` yielded a zero could keep on going, and the number of control-D's required would be determined by the number of consecutive zeroes the program required to decide it was done?

Comment: @supercat A program can keep on reading if it wants. In the `ex` editor, if you type a control-D as the first character of a line, the editor shows you a few lines of the program rather than exiting. (In `ex` and `vi`, Control-D is a mnemonic for  "down"). And with many shells, if you type Control-D but have jobs running in the background, the shell will inform you of this rather than exiting, but if you type Control-D again, the shell decides that you really want to exit anyway and will do so.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: Is there any way by which these zero-byte hiccups can be sent via pipe?

Comment: @supercat Nope. A write of zero length to a pipe is just like not having written anything to it at all.

Answer (score 28):

That's because <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is a hack.

Deep down, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> (despite being called the [`eof` character](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/xbd_chap11.html#tag_11_01_09)) doesn't actually mean end-of-file: it means “send the pending input to the application now”. This is actually close to the meaning of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> (`eol`), which sends the pending input plus a newline.

When you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> immediately after a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> (i.e. at the beginning of a line) or after another <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, the pending input is empty. Thus the application receives 0 bytes of input. In a [`read`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/read.html) call, reading 0 bytes signals the end of the file.

---

When you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, the pending input is discarded. Thus only what had already been sent to the application (which is `cat`) by entering a newline or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> before pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> is processed.

Comment: More information regarding ctrl + D from one of Gille's answer could be found [here](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16338/47538).

Comment: As you said, Ctrl-D does not mean end-of-file. In fact reason it does not mean that is because Ctrl-D is EOT (end-of-text).

Comment: You can also read `Ctrl-D` itself if you read byte-by-byte...