# What is the difference in using Ctrl+D and Ctrl+C to terminate cat command?

Tags: cat

I have the following two test files:

```
test1 test2
```

Both of them are blank. Now I issue the following commands:

```
$ cat > test1
```

<kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
This is a test file
```

<kbd>Enter</kbd>

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>

```
$ cat > test2
```

<kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
This is another test file
```

<kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
^C
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>

```
$
```

Now I check the contents of the two files

```
$ cat test1
This is a test file
$ cat test2
This is another test file
$
```

So is there any real difference in the outcome if we use the above two methods to achieve the same outcome?

Comment: Yes outcomes are different. Can you please give some explanation?

Comment: A related question is https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177651/ .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the `cat` command is running, the terminal is in *canonical input mode*.  This means, in short, that the terminal's *line discipline* is handling line editing, and is responding to all of the *special characters* configured for the terminal (viewable and settable with the `stty` command).

The `cat` command is simply `read()`ing from its standard input until a `read()` call returns zero bytes read, the POSIX convention for hitting end of file.

Terminals do not really have an "end".  But there is a circumstance where `read()` of a terminal device returns zero bytes.  When the line discipline receives the "EOF" special character, whatever that happens to be configured as at the time, it causes `read()` to return with whatever is in the editing buffer at that point.  If the editing buffer was empty, that returns zero bytes read from `read()`, causing `cat` to exit.

`cat` also exits in response to signals whose default actions are to terminate the process.  The line discipline also generates signals in response to special characters.  The "INTR" and "QUIT" special characters cause the `INT` and `QUIT` signals to be sent to the foreground process (group), which will be/contain the `cat` process.  The default action of these signals is to terminate the `cat` process.

Which leads to the observable differences:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> only has this action when it is the EOT special character.  This is *usually* the case, but it is not *necessarily* the case.  Similarly, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> only has its action when it is the INTR special character.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> will not cause `cat` to terminate when the line is not in fact empty at the time.  An interrupt generated by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will, though.
- A naïve implementation of `cat` in the C language will block buffer standard output if it finds it directed at a file, as in the question.  In theory, this could lead to buffered and not yet output lines being lost if `cat` is terminated by `SIGINT`.

  In practice, the BSD and GNU C libraries implement a buffering mode that is not described in the C or C++ language standards.  Standard output when redirected to file or pipe is *smart buffered*.  It is block buffered; except that whenever the C library finds itself about to `read()` the beginning of a new line from any file descriptor that is open to a terminal device, it flushes standard output.  (The BSD and GNU C libraries do not quite implement the same semantics and do more than this, strictly speaking, but this behaviour is a common subset.)  Thus an interrupt signal will not cause lost buffered output when `cat` is built on top of such a C library.
- Of course, if `cat` is part of a command pipeline, some *other* process could be buffering the data, downstream of `cat` before those data reach an output file.  So again when the line discipline sends `SIGINT`, which (by default) terminates all of the processes in the pipeline, input data buffered and not yet written will be lost; whereas terminating `cat` normally with the "EOF" special character will cause the pipeline to terminate normally, with all of the data passing to the downstream process before *it* receives an EOF indication from *its* `read()` of its standard input.

Note that this bears very little relationship to what happens when your interactive shell is reading a line of input from you.  When your shell is waiting for input, the terminal is in *non-canonical input mode*, in which mode the line discipline *does not do* any special handling of special characters.  How your shell treats <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is entirely up to the input editing library that your shell uses (libedit, readline, or ZLE) and how that editing library has been configured (with key bindings and suchlike).

## Further reading

- [POSIX terminal interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_terminal_interface).  Wikipedia.

Answer (score 5):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>  is an interrupt signal. It will stop the command.

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> is end of file or `exit()`. When you entered <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> , it exited from the command because of end of file. If you type <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> in your shell nothing will happen. However, if your enter <kbd>CTRl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, it will exit from your current Shell in most systems.

Comment: Apart from what are they according to definition is there any change in outcome or the outcome will always be the same, whichever method you use?

Comment: @Sonevol different. CTRL+D works like EOF and CTRL+C  is intr (check ``stty -a`` for these settings of line discipline). Try ``cat > foo.txt``. Type something, click CTRL+D and check ``foo.txt``. Check it with CTRL+C then.