# Ctrl+D vs. Enter

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

I opened `cat` without any argument in the terminal:

```
cat
```

And then I typed some text and pressed `Ctrl+D`, and what I typed was echoed back.

I re-typed some text and pressed `Enter`, and what I typed was also echoed back.

Is there a difference between `Ctrl+D` and `Enter` (I am talking about when there is text in the terminal when pressing one of these keys, because when there is no text, `Ctrl+D` sends `EOF`, while `Enter` does not).

Comment: This answer may be relevant: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/177661/88983

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enter` makes the terminal device line discipline send the current input buffer plus `\n` (translated from the `\r` sent by the terminal (emulator) by the `icrnl` setting of the line discipline) to the application which is reading from the terminal device. `^D` makes the terminal device line discipline send the current input buffer without a `\n` nor `^D` character (the character is eaten away by the line discipline unless you sent `^V` beforehand).

Pressing `^D` twice in a row makes `cat` exit because it assumes there is nothing more to read (`read()` returns 0 byte).

Comment: Pressing `^D` only one time made `cat` exit based on my testing (unless you mean pressing `^D` twice when there is text in the terminal).

Comment: @HaukeLaging This is correct but incomplete. `^D` is the default `eof` setting for the line discipline. When `eof` is detected as the __first__ character in the read buffer the current application doing the read exits. When it's detected but isn't the first character the line is flushed. This is true for at least `readline` and `libedit`. Proof: after `stty eof ^T` it's `^T` that has that effect described above, and `^D` has no effect.

Comment: @user258851 If you have not typed anything (after the last `<enter>`) then you have the same situation as if you had pressed `^D` before. Thus you need only one `^D` to make `cat` exit.

Comment: @SatōKatsura There is no difference on the side of the terminal: In both cases it sends the current buffer to the application (i.e. has (`read()` return). But usually applications exit when `read()` returns zero bytes. The `read()` does not even return with an error.

Comment: What I'm saying is `^D` behave this way because it's `stty eof`, not because it's `^D`. Also, AFAICT this behavior is incidental. If you think for 5 minutes how a line editing function should be implemented given the UNIX functions, that's the straightforward way and it also makes sense. Which is why shells do that. But to the best of my knowledge only "exit when `eof` on input" is mandated by standards. It's in principle possible to have a line editing library that doesn't flush the buffer when it sees `eof`. FWIW.