# why does the output of xargs -n2 applied to the same number of arguments different whether piped or from keyboard?

Tags: command-line, pipe, xargs

when I execute `xargs -n2`, enter `x x x x x` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I get only 4 x back:

```
$ xargs -n2
x x x x x 
x x 
x x
```

But, when I pipe the `x x x x x` into the same command, I get the same amount of x back:

```
$ echo x x x x x | xargs -n2
x x 
x x 
x
```

why is it that in the first scenario the amount of arguments is either rounded up or rounded down ?

Comment: in first case, what happen if you types in a second line with a b c ? or Ctrl-D ?

Comment: In the first case it's still waiting for input so if you hit `Ctrl+D` it'll print the remaining `x` too. See [How to signal the end of stdin input](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/16333)

Answer (score 5):

In the first line, `xargs` still waits for the second argument or an end of the input. After pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> xargs continues with the rest and you will see the 5th `x` as single argument.

This example may explain the behavior:

```
(echo "x x x x x"; sleep 5; echo "x") | xargs -n2
```

Output:

```
x x
x x
x x     # after 5 seconds
```

After the 6th `x` in the second `echo` statement the input stream is finished and `xargs` finally has the second argument, but until then it waits the 5 seconds.

Comment: Presumably this is because of the `-n 2 ` which forces `xargs` to expect arguments that are multiples of 2 right?

Comment: `xargs` can also continue with one argument if the second argument would exceed a specific size (`-s`). But, also in that case `xargs` would wait until that arguemnt came.