# How to escape standard input when "cat f - g"

Tags: cat, coreutils, stdio

`man cat` shows the following example:

```
   cat f - g
          Output f's contents, then standard input, then g's
          contents.
```

How do you escape the standard input and proceed to output the 2nd file 'g'?

Comment: Are you asking [How to signal the end of stdin input](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16333/how-to-signal-the-end-of-stdin-input) ?

Comment: Yes, Ctrl+D works. I hadn't seen that before. Thanks.